# how get the product data by attribute value in magento 2.2.0

Tags: magento

I tried the products get on front page using attribute value in magento 2.2.0
But I am facing the problem. so please let me know how get the product data by attribute value in magento 2.2.0.

Comment: "But I am facing the problem", could you be more specific? Isn't there any documentation on Magento's website for this seemingly basic task?

Comment: How it is possible? how it will be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Filter with you appropriate `tag` attribute here I'm using `popular` as my custom attribute replace it with your attribute

First of all paste this Code where you wanted to display the Collection

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productCollection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('tag', 'popular')
            ->load();
    return $collection;
```

**1)** SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer in **.htaccess** file.

**2)** Clear cache using command line php bin/magento cache:flush

**3)** Reload the front end page

**4)** After reloading the page the message will change to

> Error filtering template: Unable to write file into directory
>   \C:/xampp/htdocs/Magento/pub/media/catalog/product\cache\f073062f50e48eb0f0998593e568d857/m/b.
>   Access forbidden.

**5)** Follow this link to fix [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170376/magento-2-unable-to-write-file-into-directory-access-forbidden](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170376/magento-2-unable-to-write-file-into-directory-access-forbidden/)

**8)** Clear cache

**9)** Reload the front end page again

**10)** If you see another message after enabling developer mode you can google it.

Comment: Please let me know about tag and popular.

Comment: @shekharsaini Updated answer. Please check it.

Comment: I am facing this error We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content. Please help me about this error.

Comment: It may be issue with MySQL Query fetch. Try to turn on Developer mode `php ./bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\best4balls\Construction\Code>php ./bin/magento deploy:mode:set d
eveloper
Magento supports 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.ma
gento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html
when I run this cmd then i am finding it while i am using php version 7.1.10 please resolve this problem. Thank you

Comment: Do you have composer installed in your Magento installation folder if not download composer and `composer install`

Comment: Updated Answer Try the scenario.

Comment: sir i am not getting any solution for it.

Comment: Are you getting any error while following the above scenario. ?

Comment: No, can you tell me query for attribute code on phtml page?

Comment: sir,my attribute code is gift_ideas.please resolve my problem.

Comment: Replace `popular` with `gift_ideas`. You will get your list.

Comment: Hi sir, i put same code but i am getting a error on the page. error:-We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content.how can i resolve it.please tell me.